# Add liked posts to user account

Tags: custom-post-types, buddypress, community

I'm working on a setlist website where the users can view all the setlists from a band. I would like to have the functionality that users can add their attended setlists to their profile.

So when they go to their profile page, they'll see all the gigs attended.

My guess is to install Buddypress and start from there. But maybe there is another solution for this?

- users should be able to create a profile
- a user should be able to like or favourite (in this case "attend") the gig (= custom post type 'gig').
- they should be able to view all their gigs attended.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this site but take a look at something like this plugin: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/likebtn-like-button/

Answer (score 0):

I have utilized this plugin for a similar situation: 
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/

Your users can register and create a profile. As the plugin comes with a lot of add-ons I'm not sure if there maybe is an add-on that solves your "attend" issue. If yes, problem solved. If not you could simply add a function which saves an array of gigs to the users profile.

I believe, that you'll probably be better off using this than buddypress. Hope that helps.